# aquery post with no hashmap like in Qt

Tags: java, android, qt, blackberry-10, aquery

I am porting an app from BB10 to android. For an http request I am using AQuery.

In Qt on BB10, I can simply post data:

```
QByteArray data = "test";
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(new QUrl("example.com"));
QNetworkAccessManager manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

manager->post(request,data);
```

but in AQuery I can only find a POST method with key/value pairs (from the doc):

```
String url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("q", "androidquery");

aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

        showResult(json);

    }
});
```

Is there a way to POST just data in AQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out how to do this.

In the AQuery source, in the httpEntity method of the AbstractAjaxCallback class:

```
HttpEntity entity = null;

Object value = params.get(AQuery.POST_ENTITY);

if(value instanceof HttpEntity){                        
     entity = (HttpEntity) value;                        
} else {
    //urlencoded POST data
}
```

So all I needed to do was this:

```
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(data);
cb.param(AQuery.POST_ENTITY,entity);
```

where `cb` is my AjaxCallback object.